# Evaluate the integral using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$$\int_{\frac{-\pi}{4}}^{0} (\sec x \tan x) dx$$

I need to evaluate the integral using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: $\sec x\tan x$ is the derivative of $\sec x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=\sec(x)$.  Then $du = \sec(x) \tan(x) dx$.  We see this is just a perfect differential.  So, by the fundamental theorem, the integral is $\sec(0) - \sec(\frac{-\pi}{4}) = 1 - \sqrt{2}$

Comment: I did it this way. Thank you for the help. I didnt even think to use U-substitution.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\sec x \tan x$ is the derivative of $\sec x$.

One way to see this is to rewrite $\sec x$ and $\tan x$ in terms of sine and cosine. We get $\dfrac{\sin x}{\cos^2 x}$. Make the subsitution $u=\cos x$.

**Remark:** One version of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus says that if $f(x)$ is a well-behaved function on the interval $[a,b]$, then
$$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=F(b)-F(a),$$
where $F(x)$ is any function whose derivative is $f(x)$,

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{\frac{-\pi}{4}}^0{\sec x\tan xdx}=\sec x|_{\frac{-\pi}{4}}^{0}= \sec(0)-\sec(\frac{-\pi}{4})=1-\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Note on my edit: \sec and \tan are predefined operators in Latex.

Comment: ohh okey thank you :) i don't know about that :p